# proftpd on debian: super user and simple users with their folder

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, ftp

hi there sorry for my english im italian.
Here is what i would like to do with proftpd

i have a main user: webserver
group: www-data
must do anything in var/www/ and subfolders
( it actually works )

Then
in var/www i have two folders:
www.one.com
www.two.com

www.one.com is defaultroot for user one (group one)... is OK
www.two.com is default root for user two (group two)... is OK

DefaultRoot /var/www/www.one.com one
DefaultRoot /var/www/www.two.com two

Now the problem:
all works exept
user one cant write in www.one.com
and
user two cant write in www.two.com

seems to be normal cause all folders, subfolders and files in /var/www/ are owned by user webserver and group www-data
but how can i resolve?
how can i give privileges to user one and user two in their ows folders?

of course i dont want to set 777 to all files!

root@debian:/var/www# ls -lh
drwxr-sr-x 3 webserver www-data 4.0K Jul 24 18:07 one.dyndns.org
drwxr-sr-x 2 webserver www-data 4.0K Jul 25 04:41 two.homepc.it
-rwxr-xr-x 1 webserver www-data  177 Jul 23 09:42 index.html

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've installed Apache and ProFTP from official Debian repositories, do the following,

```
$ chmod -R g+w /var/www/www.one.com /var/www/www.two.com
$ chown -R proftpd.www-data /var/www/www.one.com /var/www/www.two.com
```

The first command gives "write" permissions to the group and the second command changes the ownership of the docroots to user: "proftpd" and group: "www-data"

If this doesn't work, please check the "User" in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf and replace it that with proftpd